# How to chain a sequence of regular expressions

Tags: regex, google-docs

I am renaming a bunch of jpegs at a time and I need to take the product description from elsewhere and combine and tidy up.

What I have come up with is a =REGEXP() for every character but this means I have some 15 columns of REGEXP's that feed into one another.

**I'm curious if there is a more efficient way. Specifically, can I combine these regexs into one simple regex?**

My process: I take the jpeg names which has the sku in the filename, paste them into a Google Doc, and then I do a vlookup for the product description based on the skus:

```
LT09-1.jpg  //starting filename example
=REGEXREPLACE(A2,"\-(.*)", "")// remove everything after the hyphen
=REGEXREPLACE(B2,".jpg", "") //take off the .jpg extension incase there wasn't a hyphen in the filename
//end up with LT09 which is the sku
```

we then vlookup the sku to get the product description, in this case "Long Tuck Carton 500mu 51 x 32 x 55mm"

```
=LOWER(SUBSTITUTE(D2," ","-")) //replace spaces with hyphens
=REGEXREPLACE(E2,",", "") //get rid of commas
=REGEXREPLACE(F2,"\(", "") //get rid of brackets left
=REGEXREPLACE(G2,"\)", "") //get rid of brackets right
=REGEXREPLACE(H2,"\&", "and") //replace ampersand with the word and
=REGEXREPLACE(I2,"-x-", "x") //get rid of certain combinations of X's and hyphens
=REGEXREPLACE(J2,"-x", "x") //get rid of certain combinations of X's and hyphens
=REGEXREPLACE(K2,"9999", "") //cannot remember what this is for lol
=REGEXREPLACE(L2,"-+-", "+") //get rid of certain combinations of +'s and hyphens
=REGEXREPLACE(M2,"\-\+", "+") //get rid of certain combinations of +'s and hyphens
=REGEXREPLACE(N2,"\.", "") //get rid of stray full stops
=REGEXREPLACE(O2,"\/", "-") //get rid of slashes
=REGEXREPLACE(P2,"\-\-", "-") // get rid of double hyphens
=REGEXREPLACE(Q2,"""", "inch") //replace quote marks with the word inch
=REGEXREPLACE(R2,"\+-", "+") //get rid of certain combinations of +'s and hyphens
=CONCATENATE(T2,"-",A2) //add the original filename and extension. Fin.
```

To turn "Long Tuck Carton 500mu 51 x 32 x 55mm" and "LT09-1.jpg" into "long-tuck-carton-500mu-51x32x55mm-LT09-1.jpg"

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to collapse some of these into one. For example, you could take all the patterns that get replaced with the empty string: Instead of

```
=REGEXREPLACE(E2,",", "")
=REGEXREPLACE(F2,"\(", "")
=REGEXREPLACE(G2,"\)", "")
=REGEXREPLACE(K2,"9999", "")
=REGEXREPLACE(N2,"\.", "")
```

you should be able to do

```
=REGEXREPLACE(E2,"[,\(\)\.]|9999", "")
```

(I haven't bothered to adjust the cell names, btw.)

Similarly for `x`s:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(I2,"-x-", "x")
=REGEXREPLACE(J2,"-x", "x")
```

becomes

```
=REGEXREPLACE(I2,"-x-?", "x")
```

And for `+`s:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(L2,"-\+-", "+")
=REGEXREPLACE(M2,"-\+", "+")
=REGEXREPLACE(R2,"\+-", "+")
```

becomes

```
=REGEXREPLACE(R2,"-\+-?|\+-", "+")
```

Note, of course, that this only works if you're *not* relying on the sequential nature of the replacements to create sequences with one call to replace with a later one.